# Is there any difference between bash command and shell scripting language?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Actually i am learning shell scripting through a eBook but after finishing some capture i face that i can write script on shell and that is executable without giving `sh script-name` command in terminal.

I search more on internet a find that there are difference source for `shell scripting` and `bash command`.

> So what is the difference between them and which should learn first ?

Comment: @inquisitor , which i should learn first ?

Comment: There is a very good explanation here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash